# Reset timer after a certain condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

The while loop in the game() only runs for 10 sec. I want to reset the time (run the while loop for 10 sec again). when certain conditions are meet. The code below is not even executing the if condition.

```
import time
gametime = time.time()+ 10
def game(): 
    print("Seconds since epoch =", gametime)    
    var = 1
    while time.time() < gametime:
        print ("hello")
        hello = input("reset time: ")
        print("test1")
        if (hello == var):
            print("test")
            print(gametime)
            reset()

    print("time is up")


def reset():
    global gametime
    gametime = time.time()+ 10

game()
```

Comment: in your if-statement you should cast the variables to the same type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the `hello` variable as `int`.

This seems to be working:

```
        if (int(hello) == var):
            print("test")
            print(gametime)
            reset()
```